# Html data not shown in view-source angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom, angular8

when i make a build of the project i can not see the meta tags on view source, but when put static data it is shown to view source but i can put dynamic data it show nothing in view-source, for this i use angular universal.

I use angular 8 for this

```
this.meta.addTags([
            {name: 'keywords', content: this.blogDetails.seo_keywords_en},
            {name: 'title', content: this.blogDetails.seo_title_en},
            {name: 'slug', content: this.blogDetails.seo_url_slug_en},
            {name: 'description', content: this.blogDetails.seo_description_en},
            {property: 'og:title', content: this.blogDetails.seo_title_en},
            {property: 'og:description', content: this.blogDetails.seo_description_en},
            {property: 'og:image', content: this.blogDetails.photo_file_seo},
            {property: 'twitter:description', content: this.blogDetails.seo_description_en},
            {property: 'twitter:title', content: this.blogDetails.seo_title_en},
            {property: 'twitter:image', content: this.blogDetails.photo_file},
        ], true);
```

it never show any error but the data is not render and i use this command to build and render the data

```
npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr
```